# Adding whitespace buffer to the border of panels in a facet plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

When creating a facet plot with `ggplot2` and `coord_polar` my x axis labels fall very close to and sometimes get cut off by the border of the panel.

Therefore I wish to increase the whitespace that borders the plot itself (inside of the panel border). The following example uses `mtcars` to show the sort of plot I am creating.

All my testing with `margin` so far has increased the whitespace around the whole plot (incorporating all panels) rather than individual panels. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
library(ggplot2)

cars <- c(rep("ford",8),rep("vauxhall",8),rep("renault",8),rep("tesla",8))
mtcars <- cbind(mtcars,cars)

#plot
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cars,y=mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "darkgrey", colour = NA, alpha = 0.75) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=12, margin = margin(t= 50)),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")) +
  xlab("") +
  coord_polar(start=-0.4) +
  facet_grid(gear ~ am, scales = "free") 

ggsave("C:/Sandbox/myplot.png",plot = last_plot(), width = 130, height = 177, units = "mm", dpi = 900)
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example illustrating the clash, please.

Comment: have modified the code in the question